# Classify sentence into predefined category

Tags: nlp

I am working on a project which takes text data (Social Media , reviews etc) and classify into a predefined category.

Now I already have a Sentiment Analyzer in place. So basically I am only working with Negative sentiment text.

Now I have a predefined category ex. 'Data speed is slow', 'No Network Coverage' etc. The total number of category is around 30.

My goal is to classify those text into those categories.

I have already tried few methods with limited success:
1. Defining Anagrams (bi and tri) for each category and then filtering.
2. Converting sentences to Sentence Vector Embedding and finding cosine similarity between sentence embedding and  an embedding for a category template.
3. KMeans Clustering and LDA.

Note : I don't have an option for labeling now so cannot do supervised learning. But I wanted to know whether Supervised learning would be the best option here.

I wanted to know the best strategy here using unsupervised technique. How to accurately capture the semantics and classify. Any traditional NLP approach which can be used here?.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try topic modeling?

Comment: @Peter Yes I tried with LDA but the result was very unsatisfactory. Also tried clustering...But since my category are fixed are the data is huge these does not help...What I want is kind of filtering....